# R - Select rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: ID_CUST, ID_TRANSACTION, TRANSACTION_MONTH.

Let's imagine the following dataframe:

```
ID_CUSTOMER    ID_TRANSACTION       TRANSACTION_MONTH
2              43                     2
2              94                     5
2              99                     8 
3              102                    4
5              121                    12
```

I first select only transactions for a period:

df_subset <- DM_TRAFFIC %>% filter(MONTH >=2 & MONTH <=5)

```
ID_CUSTOMER    ID_TRANSACTION       TRANSACTION_MONTH
2              43                     2
2              94                     5
3              102                    4
```

From those transactions, I then wish to keep all transactions from customers who made a transaction in Month 5.

```
ID_CUSTOMER    ID_TRANSACTION       TRANSACTION_MONTH
2              43                     2
2              94                     5
```

I'm a bit confused on how to tackle this step .

If you have the solution in dplyr or datatable, it would be even more appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Would you be able to post a reproducible sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your first subset, use `group_by` to filter by each `ID_CUSTOMER`. Then use `filter` and `any` to look for a group that has at least one value satisfying the condition.

**dplyr**

```
DM_TRAFFIC %>% 
  filter(TRANSACTION_MONTH >=2 & TRANSACTION_MONTH <=5) %>%
  group_by(ID_CUSTOMER) %>%
  filter(any(TRANSACTION_MONTH == 5))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: ID_CUSTOMER [1]
#
#  ID_CUSTOMER ID_TRANSACTION TRANSACTION_MONTH
#        (int)          (int)             (int)
#1           2             43                 2
#2           2             94                 5
```

**data.table**

```
setDT(DM_TRAFFIC)[TRANSACTION_MONTH >= 2 & TRANSACTION_MONTH <= 5][
  , if(any(TRANSACTION_MONTH == 5)) .SD,by = ID_CUSTOMER]
#   ID_CUSTOMER ID_TRANSACTION TRANSACTION_MONTH
#1:           2             43                 2
#2:           2             94                 5
```